# How to use Angular directives inside ui-gmap-window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to use Angular directives inside `ui-gmap-window`. I realized one must move the HTML into a template file in order to do this. Here is my `ui-gmap-window` code:

```
<ui-gmap-window
  show="playerMap.window.show"
  coords="playerMap.window.model"
  options="playerMap.window.options"
  closeclick="playerMap.window.closeClick()"
  templateUrl="'/app/dmPlayerMap/infoWindow.html'"
  templateParameter="playerMap.infoWindowParams">
</ui-gmap-window>
```

and here is infoWindow.html:

```
<div ng-if="true">
  <p>I'm true!!!</p>
</div>
```

Every time I click the marker to open the infoWindow 'I'm true!!!' is printed again. So, for example, after ten clicks it's printed ten times. Also, I noticed the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined`. If I remove the `ng-if` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive as to why, but it appears that Angular directives cannot live on the top-level element within the template. I changed infoWindow.html to the following and it now works cleanly:

```
<div>
  <div ng-if="true">
    <p>I'm true!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also of note, you cannot have two top-level elements. In the below example the last div will not appear:

```
<div>
  <div ng-if="true">
    <p>I'm true!!!</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="true">
    <p>I'm not false!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div ng-if="true">
    <p>I won't appear!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```